# Не приходит ответ с сервера

Tags: angular2, express

Добрый вечер!
Проблема с Mean stack(angular2). 
Есть поле ввода данных для запроса на сервер - название города по котором надо вывести погоду.

Данные посылаются в POST запросе, сервер их обработал но обратно на фронт не возвращает данные. Проходит полминуты и в панели разработчика, в консоль выдает error::empty_response

код обработки запроса на сервере:

```
router.post('/search', (async (req, res) => {

let city =  req.body.city;

const apiKey = '79db9599e21f6fa00d36539b86173cd3';

var options = {

uri: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?
 q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=7b359dd1309d346d33a02be66852222`,
headers: {'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'},json: true}
 res.body = await rp(options)

.then(function(city) {
   return city.list;
})
.catch(function (err) {
    throw(err);
});
}));
```

код сервиса

```
  getWeather(data) : Observable<any> {
     const ep = this.prepEndpoint('api/search');
        return this.http.post(ep, {city: data})
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error:any) => {
      return Observable.throw(error);
        });             
    }
```

Comment: Ответ в консоли разработчика

POST http://localhost:3000/api/search net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Проверь получает ли данные бэкенд

Comment: Да, запрос проходит и обработка запроса тоже есть а вот ответ на сервер не идет.

Comment: ответ на клиент?

Comment: Да, ошибся ответ на клиент не идет. Выдает такую ошибку
POST localhost:3000/api/search net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE –

Answer (score 0):

А где вы посылаете ответ клиенту? res.status(200).send(city.list);[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/205903)

Comment: Почему не является ?

Answer (score -1):

На стороне сервера необходимо писать `res.send` вместо `res.body`.